# Laravel collection 2nd result set relationship always null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a query where I'm returning a one to many relationship I'm expecting two results both with their relationship. The first result returns correctly but after the first result, I always get a `NULL` value for my relationship data for every result after the first.

If I delete the 1st record in my database the 2nd then becomes the first and it returns correctly.

This is my query -

```
$groups = DataGroup::where('post_id', $post->id)->with('data.dataType')->get();
```

DataGroup relationship

```
public function data()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Data', 'data_group_id');
}
```

Data relationships

```
public function dataType()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\DataTypes', 'id');
}

public function dataGroup()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\DataGroup', 'id');
}
```

DataType relationship

```
public function data()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Data', 'data_types_id');
}
```

The result set (stripped out other information for easier reading)

```
Collection {#259 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => Data {#272 ▼
      #fillable: array:5 [▶]
      #attributes: array:8 [▶]
      #original: array:8 [▶]
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "dataType" => DataTypes {#271 ▶}
      ]
    }
    1 => Data {#268 ▼
      #fillable: array:5 [▶]
      #attributes: array:8 [▶]
      #original: array:8 [▶]
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "dataType" => null
      ]
```

Data Groups Table

```
---------------------
| id | post_id      |
--------------------
| 1  | 2            |
--------------------
```

Data Types table

```
---------------------
| id | label | name |
--------------------
| 1  | Text  | text |
--------------------
```

Data table

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| id | data_types_id | data_group_id | field_label | value |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |  1            | 1             | Title       | NULL  |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  |  1            | 1             | Sub Heading | NULL  |
```

Comment: Can you try to run the code in this order: `$groups = DataGroup::with('data.dataType')->where('post_id', $post->id)->get();` Ive noticed in the past this can give different results(doing with before where). If that fails, could you show us your database data?( maybe write a query with join and show us what the results should be :) )

Comment: Thanks @RobBiermann I tired your query but I still got that `null` value on the relationship I've updated my question with the DB tables.

Comment: Thanks for your info, it helped me getting a conclusion ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you change:

```
public function dataType()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\DataTypes', 'id');
}
```

into:

```
public function dataType()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\DataTypes', 'data_type_id');
}
```

that should resolve the problem, it is currently trying to refer to a datatype with id 2(which is the id of data 2), which does not exist.

Look at the lower part of the https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one paragraph, it describes you need to enter foreign key as 2nd variable of the relationship definition, not the local key.

BTW: Your other relationship has the same problem:

```
public function dataGroup()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\DataGroup', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Yes, well spotted the fact 1 object was returning was just pure luck as they were the first instances of the database. I was defining the local keys first instead of correctly assigning the foreign keys. Thank you